# Calling C++ Library from Android via JNI without recompiling using NDK?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

This is a somewhat large C++ library, I already have the compiled library, is there anyway I can use the library without recompiling it using NDK? Would I need a C++ or CWrapper that would load the pre-compiled library.  Can this be done or not?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be possible using  NDK r5b or later, as previous versions did not support pre-built 3rd party libraries.  I don't see good documentation of this however?